# Dependecy Injection troubles: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.1

Ok, I am making a Api, trying to use DI.

My Controller:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TerminalsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IServiceWrapper _service;

        public TerminalsController(IServiceWrapper service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] Message object)
        {
            try
            {

                Result result = await _service.Terminal.UpsertInfo(ternminalObject);

                if (result.shopId != -1 || result.deviceId != -1 || result.companyId != -1)
                {
                    return Ok(result);
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Can not save info from session on database");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            }
        }
    }
```

And the code of my service:

```
public class TerminalService : ITerminalService
    {
        private readonly IRepositoryWrapper _repository;

        public TerminalService(IRepositoryWrapper repository) 
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<Result> UpsertInfo(company company)
        {
            try
            {
                var company = await _repository.Company.GetById(int.Parse(company.Id))

                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
    }
```

When my code rise the line

```
 var company = await _repository.Company.GetById(int.Parse(company.Id))
```

I get the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

Here there are my others class:

My factory:

```
 public class DbClientFactory<T>
    {
        private static Lazy<T> _factoryLazy = new Lazy<T>(
            () => (T)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T)),
            LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

        public static T Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return _factoryLazy.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The factory instace the service and the repositories.

This is my StartUp.cs:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            SqlHelper.connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CONNECTION_STRING");
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureCors();
            services.AddMvc();
            services.ConfigureServiceWrapper();
            services.ConfigureRepositoryWrapper();
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.All
            });

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

The ConfigureRepositoryWrapper and the ConfigureServiceWrapper are in the ServiceExtensions.cs:

```
 public static class ServiceExtensions
    {
        public static void ConfigureCors(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod());
            });
        }
        public static void ConfigureRepositoryWrapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IRepositoryWrapper, RepositoryWrapper>();
        }
        public static void ConfigureServiceWrapper(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<IServiceWrapper, ServiceWrapper>();
        }
    }
```

The implement of ServiceWrapper is:

```
 public class ServiceWrapper : IServiceWrapper
    {
        private ITerminalService _terminal;

        public ITerminalService Terminal {
            get
            {
                if (_terminal == null)
                {
                    _terminal = DbClientFactory<TerminalService>.Instance;
                }
                return _terminal;
            }
        }
    }
```

And the implement of RepositoryWrapper is:

```
public class RepositoryWrapper : IRepositoryWrapper
    {
        private IDeviceRepository _device;
        private IShopRepository _shop;
        private ICompanyRepository _company;
        public IDeviceRepository Device
        {
            get
            {
                if (_device == null)
                {
                    _device = DbClientFactory<DeviceRepository>.Instance;
                }
                return _device;
            }
        }

        public IShopRepository Shop
        {
            get
            {
                if (_shop == null)
                {
                    _shop = DbClientFactory<ShopRepository>.Instance;
                }
                return _shop;
            }
        }

        public ICompanyRepository Company {
            get {
                if (_company == null)
                {
                    _company = DbClientFactory<CompanyRepository>.Instance;
                }
                return _company;
            }
        }
    }
```

I really dont know what is wrong here...

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @marc_s, no, the problem is that i dont know why I get this error, because I thinks I am initializating all right

Comment: Are you debugging? Is the company.Id an actual value or null? Also change the name of the object you are initializing, you cannot have a parameter named `company` and another instance within the method named `company`.

Comment: I now see that you are trying to pass in the service into a non service class. That is why it is null. You will need to pass the`IRepositoryWrapper` into the controller, then pass that value into the constructor when you call`TerminalService`.

Comment: Hi @JoséPabloMedinaGrande  I think you can add a break at line `var company = await _repository.Company.GetById(int.Parse(company.Id))` to check if `_repository` is null or the parameter `company` is null.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `company.Id` does not exist.

```
var company = await _repository.Company.GetById(int.Parse(company.Id));
```

You are creating/fetching an object named `company` and at the same already have an object passed in that is named `company`, you can not do have two variables or objects in the same scope with the same name. Rename one of the objects from `company` to something else.

Also you likely are not passing in an object in the parameter, you are probably passing in null which is the reason for `company.Id` not existing. Check the value you are passing in, and rename one of the items.

```
var newCompany = await _repository.Company.GetById(int.Parse(company.Id));
```

If the exception is happening on `_repository`, the reason is that you are trying to pass a dependency into a non service class. To fix it, pass the dependency into the controller, then when initializing `TerminalService` just pass in the `_repository`. Also make sure that `_service.Terminal` is instantiated.

```
public class TerminalsController : ControllerBase
{
     private readonly IServiceWrapper _service;
     private readonly IRepositoryWrapper _repository;

    public TerminalsController(IServiceWrapper service, IRepositoryWrapper repository)
    {
         _service = service;
         _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post([FromBody] Message object)
    {
        _service.Terminal = new TerminalService(_repository);
        Result result = await _service.Terminal.UpsertInfo(ternminalObject);

        //remaining code    
    }
}
```

Comment: The null is in _repostory, not in the object... is like the constructor cant Inject the deendecy

Comment: Instead of calling `services.ConfigureRepositoryWrapper();` in the ConfigureServices method of Startup. Have you tried just having `services.AddScoped<IRepositoryWrapper, RepositoryWrapper>();` in the `ConfigureServices` method instead?

Comment: What is the benefit of having `ConfigureREpositoryWrapper()` if all it does is `services.AddScoped<IRepositroyWrapper, RepositoryWrapper>();`? Why not just call `AddScoped` within the ConfigureServices method in Startup? My guess is that the dependency injection is not working because of this.

Comment: I just realized that you are trying to use dependency injection on a non service class. Since the class is not a controller, you should accept the service on the controller that will call the `TerminalService` class and pass it in the constructor. Startup by default will pass dependencies into controllers.

Comment: hi xtryingx.. I tryed that you said in your commetn and still get the null exception.... and I dont know what you mean  in the last coment....

Comment: In the last comment I am saying to pass `private readonly IRepositoryWrapper _repository;` into the TerminalsController. It will have two parameters now, the IServiceWrapper and IRepositoryWrapper. Then when you need to call TerminalService, instantiate a new TerminalService and pass _repository from the TerminalContoller into the constructor of TerminalService.

Comment: I have made updates to my answer. Look at the last chunk.

Comment: Hi @xtrying....but, this dont make that DI stop making sense??